# Python - PayPal recurring Payments - Agreement Details are not shown

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

In my python project I have to implement paypal recurring payments.
I have installed the paypal sdk and created a file to create a PayPal payment page, like this:

```
import paypalrestsdk
from paypalrestsdk import BillingPlan
from paypalrestsdk import BillingAgreement
from paypalrestsdk import Payment
import webbrowser
from urllib import parse

paypalrestsdk.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox',  # sandbox or live
    'client_id': <my app client id>,
    'client_secret': <my app secret>})


def create_bill():
    billing_plan = BillingPlan({
        "name": "Plan with Regular and Trial Payment Definitions",
        "description": "Plan with regular and trial payment definitions.",
        "type": "INFINITE",
        "payment_definitions": [
            {
                "name": "Regular payment definition",
                "type": "REGULAR",
                "frequency": "MONTH",
                "frequency_interval": "1",
                "amount": {
                    "value": "100",
                    "currency": "USD"
                },
                "cycles": "0",
                "charge_models": [
                    {
                        "type": "SHIPPING",
                        "amount": {
                            "value": "10",
                            "currency": "USD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "TAX",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": "12",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Trial payment definition",
            "type": "TRIAL",
            "frequency": "WEEK",
            "frequency_interval": "5",
            "amount": {
                "value": "9.19",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "cycles": "2",
            "charge_models": [
                {
                    "type": "SHIPPING",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": "1",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "TAX",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": "2",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "merchant_preferences": {
        "setup_fee": {
            "value": "1",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "return_url": "https://example.com",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel",
        "auto_bill_amount": "YES",
        "initial_fail_amount_action": "CONTINUE",
        "max_fail_attempts": "0"
    }
})

# Create billing plan
if billing_plan.create():
    print("Billing Plan [%s] created successfully" % billing_plan.id)

    # Activate billing plan
    if billing_plan.activate():
        billing_plan = BillingPlan.find(billing_plan.id)
        print("Billing Plan [%s] state changed to %s" % (billing_plan.id, billing_plan.state))
        return billing_plan
    else:
        print(billing_plan.error)
else:
    print(billing_plan.error)


def create_agreement(ret_bil):

    billing_agreement = BillingAgreement({
        "name": "Fast Speed Agreement",
        "description": "Agreement for Fast Speed Plan",
        "start_date": "2018-03-29T00:37:04Z",
        "plan": {
            "id": str(ret_bil.id)
        },
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "shipping_address": {
            "line1": "StayBr111idge Suites",
            "line2": "Cro12ok Street",
            "city": "San Jose",
            "state": "CA",
            "postal_code": "95112",
            "country_code": "US"
        }
    })

    if billing_agreement.create():
        # Extract redirect url
        for link in billing_agreement.links:
            if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                # Capture redirect url
                redirect_url = str(link.href)
                # REDIRECT USER TO redirect_url
                webbrowser.open(redirect_url)

    else:
        print(billing_agreement.error)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_agreement(create_bill())
```

But when I run the code above, Paypal starts with agreement description but I can't see the item details and description defined in the BilingPlan (I expected to see the detail about items, trial period, amount, recurrence etc)

[image]

Is there something wrong in my code? This is the first time I implement Paypal in my project; have I written my code correctly to implement recurrent payments?

So many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

PayPal will not show the recurring period, amount and service details. 
You have to show that in your website's page and proceed to PayPal.

Comment: i noticed with this it shows pre-approved https://imgur.com/a/Sp7JdVC ? what does this mean, how do I know if it is charged to the customer. is there an additional steps for this to make sure customer is charged ? Thanks. @Sundar